# UIWebView becomes too big when using iOS 6/7 Deltas

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uiwebview, xcode5

I have a UIWebView in my app. Due to the differences between iOS 6 and iOS 7, it has be a slightly different size. I'm trying to achieve this with iOS 6/7 deltas in IB. It seems like this should be easy, but it's not working right. On iOS 6, the UIWebView needs to have a height of 373 and on iOS 7 it needs to have a height of 393. However, when I set the height in iOS 6/7 deltas, it's fine on iOS 7 but when it's run on iOS 6 the UIWebView's height increases to 745. That is way too big. I've also had this problem the other way around (where it's fine on iOS 6 but way to big on iOS 7). I can't figure out why this is happening. Does it have something to do with the way iOS 6/7 deltas work? Is there another solution?

Here are my deltas:

With "View as iOS 6.1 and Earlier" enabled:

[image: With "View as iOS 6.1 and Earlier" enabled]

With "View as iOS 7.0 and Later" enabled:

[image: With "View as iOS 7.0 and Later" enabled]

Also something I should have mentioned before is I'm not using Autolayout as I want to maintain compatibility with iOS 4.3.

Comment: Can you show us what values for the deltas you are using?

Comment: So thats your problem, the delta, is the difference between the values of the two versions. A delta of 393 means that you add 393 to the height of the view when going to iOS 6 from 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how deltas work.

"Delta" means the "difference", as you have used when setting the y value.
If the views have the same height, simply set the delta of the height to 0. If the height is different, set the delta to the difference.

Comment: Thanks alot. That was the problem. Glad I asked because I never would have figured that out on my own.